# Free jqGrid 4.11 - Unformat from http link format during edit

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Suppose I'm adding a format to a cell that looks like this:

```
return '<a href="' + cellvalue + '" target="_blank">Click Here</a>';
```

Now, if user is trying to 'edit' the cell, he will be presented with the value 'Click Here' for editing, and not with the actual url.

How can I make the actual url appear when user choose to edit this row?

Thanks,

Tal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define unformatter. The code could be the following

```
unformat: function (cellvalue, options, elem) {
    return $(elem).children("a").attr("href");
}
```

or

```
unformat: function (cellvalue, options, elem) {
    return $(elem).find("a").attr("href");
}
```

The first parameter of `unformat` callback is *the text* from the cell, but the 3-d parameter is *the DOM element* of parent of `<a>` which you create by the formatter.